# New line character ini file inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In my inno code I write a string to ini file for instance:

```
{"TrackUrl"="http://ext-feed.databssint.com/"\n"Offers"=[{"DownloadUrl"="http://dehosting.dmccint.com/FeedStub/1.4.0.5.150107.02/stub.exe"\n"OfferCMD"="OfferID=553565;
```

Before I write this string to the ini file I wish to modify it and replace all the "," characters with new line character, I tried to use:

```
StringChangeEx(MyStringVar, ',', \n  , False);
```

but instead to add a new line it replace the "," with "\n"
does anybody know how to pass the ini file a new line command character ?

Comment: INI file is a line based file structure. Text that you break on a new line will be treated as a potential section or key value string. Anyway, line break is `#13#10` in Inno Setup.

Comment: Tnaks Tlama, I passed it as so- StringChangeEx(MyStringVar, ',', #13#10  , False); and it works!

Comment: You're welcome! I've suggested you how to break your INI file by an invalid JSON :) What you're going to do is wrong.

Comment: It's Ok I fixed the invalid JSON

Comment: For those who are interested: you can add every character from the ASCII  Table, by prepending an '#'-character before the ASCII-Code-Number (decimal). #9 is (horizontal) TAB for example. #13#10 is nothing else than Carriage Return (ASCII 13) and Line Feed (ASCII 10)

Comment: Thanks. The double CR `#13#13` is well used in the [CodeExample1](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Examples/CodeExample1.iss).